# Can not install ruby 2.5.1 by rbenv on ubuntu vps

Tags: ruby, ubuntu, vps, rbenv, diskspace

I try to install ruby 2.5.1 on my vps `Ubuntu 18.04`, when I run command `rbenv install 2.5.1`. It show an error

```
/home/bet/.rbenv/plugins/ruby-build/bin/ruby-build: line 1295: cannot create temp file for here-document: No space left on device
mktemp: failed to create directory via template ‘/tmp/ruby-build.20200313131832.28894.XXXXXX’: No space left on device
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘’: No such file or directory

BUILD FAILED (Ubuntu 18.04 using ruby-build 20200224-6-gd8019fe)

Inspect or clean up the working tree at
```

I try to check disk space by command `df -h`. It show

```
Filesystem                         Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev                               463M     0  463M   0% /dev
tmpfs                               99M  1.2M   98M   2% /run
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv  3.9G  3.8G     0 100% /
tmpfs                              493M     0  493M   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs                              5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs                              493M     0  493M   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda2                          976M  145M  806M  16% /boot
tmpfs                               99M     0   99M   0% /run/user/1000
/dev/loop2                          92M   92M     0 100% /snap/core/8592
tmpfs                               99M     0   99M   0% /run/user/1001
/dev/loop0                          92M   92M     0 100% /snap/core/8689
tmpfs                               99M     0   99M   0% /run/user/1002
```

So anyone can help me. Thank you

Comment: This usually happens when the size of the temporary file that rbenv is creating exceeds the size of `/tmp/` directory. I onced faced it when I allocated less space for /tmp while installing ubuntu. What is the size of your `/tmp/` directory?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I resolved it.